# Amazon Instance Volume Full

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

When I go to the AWS Console, it says that my volume has 20GB.
However, if I do a `df -h`, it shows the following:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  7.7G  118M  99% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

We are the remaining 10GB? My volume's type is standard.

Is there a way to resize the partition?

Comment: what kind of instance? `m3.large`, `c3.xlarge`, `m4.small`?

Comment: It's a m3.medium

Comment: Are you confusing instance storage with EBS storage?

Comment: It's possible :( What the difference?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Storage.html

Comment: Basically, my files lies on an EBS storage of 10GB and the instance storage of 20GB is used to store temp data?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: I just took a look on my Volumes and it's size is 20 GiB. I'm confused.

Comment: The block devices may be 20GiB. That doesn't necessarily mean the filesystem is 20GiB. You might need to resize your filesystem.

Comment: Got it. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` and now my partition has 20GiB